# Entity Framework Generator For Postgres

Tags: postgresql, asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I found a nice article in http://www.loresoft.com/Generate-ASP-NET-Web-API. I've read and test it with the SQL Server database with success. Now, I want to change the database engine into PostgreSQL, I've migrated the database from SQL Server into PostgreSQL.

But, When I am executing:

```
efg generate -c ""Host=localhost;Username=admin;Database=dbTest;Password=admin;Persist Security Info=True""
```

The console showing me:

```
17:18:04 W Option file not found: generation.yml
17:18:04 I Using default options
17:18:04 D Creating database model factory for: SqlServer
17:18:04 I Loading database model ...
17:18:04 F Host terminated unexpectedly
System.ArgumentException: Keyword not supported: 'host'.
   at Microsoft.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions.ParseInternal(Dictionary`2 parsetable, String connectionString, Boolean buildChain, Dictionary`2 synonyms, Boolean firstKey)
   at Microsoft.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions..ctor(String connectionString, Dictionary`2 synonyms)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionString..ctor(String connectionString)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnectionOptions(String connectionString, DbConnectionOptions previous)
   at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.GetConnectionPoolGroup(DbConnectionPoolKey key, DbConnectionPoolGroupOptions poolOptions, DbConnectionOptions& userConnectionOptions)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.ConnectionString_Set(DbConnectionPoolKey key)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.set_ConnectionString(String value)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection..ctor(String connectionString)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Scaffolding.Internal.SqlServerDatabaseModelFactory.Create(String connectionString, DatabaseModelFactoryOptions options)
   at EntityFrameworkCore.Generator.CodeGenerator.GetDatabaseModel(IDatabaseModelFactory factory) in C:\projects\entityframeworkcore-generator\src\EntityFrameworkCore.Generator.Core\CodeGenerator.cs:line 371
   at EntityFrameworkCore.Generator.CodeGenerator.Generate(GeneratorOptions options) in C:\projects\entityframeworkcore-generator\src\EntityFrameworkCore.Generator.Core\CodeGenerator.cs:line 40
   at EntityFrameworkCore.Generator.GenerateCommand.OnExecute(CommandLineApplication application) in C:\projects\entityframeworkcore-generator\src\EntityFrameworkCore.Generator\GenerateCommand.cs:line 76
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at McMaster.Extensions.CommandLineUtils.Conventions.ExecuteMethodConvention.Invoke(MethodInfo method, Object instance, Object[] arguments)
   at McMaster.Extensions.CommandLineUtils.Conventions.ExecuteMethodConvention.OnExecute(ConventionContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at McMaster.Extensions.CommandLineUtils.Conventions.ExecuteMethodConvention.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<<Apply>b__0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at McMaster.Extensions.CommandLineUtils.CommandLineApplication.ExecuteAsync(String[] args, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at McMaster.Extensions.CommandLineUtils.CommandLineApplication.Execute(String[] args)
   at EntityFrameworkCore.Generator.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\projects\entityframeworkcore-generator\src\EntityFrameworkCore.Generator\Program.cs:line 50
```

I think I was missing some dependencies package. But, I am not sure what is it.

Thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found the solution, and decide to post it here because It may help other people in the future.

Actually, `efg` command will use SqlServer provider if we not mentioning any "provider" parameter. So, I've revised my command into:

```
efg generate -c "Host=localhost;Username=admin;Database=dbTest;Password=admin;Persist Security Info=True" -p PostgreSQL
```